# Import of Unknown directives dbquery, sdl

Tags: javascript, graphql, using-directives

I'm using Stepzen, it generated graphql files, however, all of them with errors:

[stepzen/index.graphql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VmhD.png)

```graphql
schema @sdl(files: ["postgresql/index.graphql"]) {
  query: Query
}
```

[stepzen/postgresql/index.graphql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhDVo.png)

```graphql
type Query {
  getCommentList: [Comment]
    @dbquery(
      type: "postgresql"
      schema: "public"
      table: "comment"
      configuration: "postgresql_config"
    )
 }
```

I can't understand how to import them correctly to fix the errors.
Sorry, if it's a stupid question...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved, the error messages you are facing, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Hello @NicoHaase, here: https://github.com/mordaKota/reddit-test-task-nextjs/blob/dev/stepzen/postgresql/index.graphql

You can see the error in the screenshots in links in this post

Comment: Please share all details by adding them to your question